# Caching in OrientDB causing inconsistency problems

Tags: java, orientdb, orientdb2.2

I have a serious problem with caching for my app using OrientDB.

I have a transaction modifying a Vertex and successfully saving it. Then, upon subsequent accesses, the results are way too inconsistent. I have confirmed this by stopping and restarting the app which will always bring me the expected results.

I have tried using getLocalCache().invalidate() and getLocalCache().clear() and also getLocalCache().updateRecord() and getLocalCache().deleteRecord() of ODatabaseDocumentTx and it still does not work. (Is this because I'm manipulating a Graph object, but I'm also using OLINK within the Graph object?)

Could anyone tell me how to resolve this problem? How do I clear/delete the cache for the updated records? Thanks!

Comment: This problem is verified by doing a RESTful call to retrieve the data: by reloading the same RESTful call using a web browser, it produces different results each time.

Comment: What version are you using? According to http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Caching.html db.getLocalCache().invalidate(); should work

Comment: Could you create an issue in bug tracker so it will be fixed ?

Comment: Does this work in OrientDB 2.2.37 by now ?